# Isset check on Array - Blade Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-5.8

If I do

`{{ dd($alert) }}`

I got

```
array:7 [▼
  "created_at" => "2019-12-30 17:31:55.728307+00:00"
  "fail_cnt" => 123
  "updated_at" => "2019-12-30 17:31:55.728307+00:00"
]
```

Hints: It is an *array*, not an object.

I'm trying to use the isset check on an array

```
<input required type="number" name="slaac" class="form-control form-control-sm"  placeholder="1000" value="{{ $alert['slaac_threshold'] or '' }}">
```

I kept getting

[image]

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: would it be safe to assume you are using PHP7?

Comment: Yes. I am. I used php 7.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the null coalescing operator `??` instead:

```
{{ $alert['slaac_threshold'] ?? '' }}
```

The `OR` operator in Blade was removed in Laravel 5.7 and never quite worked correctly.

> "The Blade "or" operator has been removed in favor of PHP's built-in `??` "null coalesce" operator, which has the same purpose and functionality" - [Laravel 5.7 Docs - Upgrade Guide - Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/upgrade)

[PHP.net Manual - 7.0 New Features - Null Coalesce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)